# Create a Tic-Tac-Toe Animation

Tags: java, jquery, ruby, flash

I want to create a simple animation of a game so you can see the playout of a game. It should be an animation in which you just see the game Tic-Tac-Toe played. I have the states of the games in a description. So player 1 marks a cell = state 1; player 2 marks a cell = state 2 etc..

I currently have the game parsed in a ruby program; it will be easy to display just one state (like in the image), but how do I create an animation from it? Is there an easy way to do this? I'm open to solutions in every language but it shouldn't take to much time to implement. I want to show such an animation in a presentation.

[image: TicTacToe Format for one state]

```
<state1>
cell(1,1,x).
cell(1,2,o).
cell(1,3,o).
cell(2,1,o).
cell(2,2,x).
cell(2,3,x).
cell(3,1,b).
cell(3,2,b).
cell(3,3,x).
</state1>

<state2>
...
</state2>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be an animation from the <state></state> examples. (The actual game I'll be using it for is Breakthrough, but because not everybody might now that game & the <state>-description is longer, I used tic-tac-toe as example)

Comment: @Joris What be the dots for ? `cell(1,1,x)`**.** <<<

Comment: That's a pretty complex state representation.  You only need a nine character string `X X OXOXO`, or 18 bits for each state in tic-tac-toe.  Likewise, for breakthrough, you would only need a 64 character string or 128 bits per state, assuming no fancy compression, etc.

Comment: I don't know if optimizing down to 18 bits would be wise, but yeah the current representation is way more verbose than it needs to be.

Comment: @phwd originally it's a writeout from a Prolog program :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I used ruby shoes and an approach similar to the post of jhocking to solve it :) http://shoesrb.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know how to display one state, the way to animate that is to display each state one after the other in sequence.

Display the first state and set a timer, then when the timer goes off show the next state and set another delay, and so on through all the states.

Since you said you are open to all languages I don't really want to bother with any specific code beyond that high-level overview. For example, in Flash/ActionScript I would use TweenLite to display the symbols with a delay, but I don't know if that specific code would be of any use to you.

I've never programmed Ruby but it probably has a command like setDelay() or setTimer() or something. If not, the same effect can be accomplished with a main loop that will check the time each cycle and if the delay has been long enough it shows the next state.

Answer (score 0):

For ruby you can have a awesome tic-tac-toe from https://github.com/grosser/tic_tac_toe

just do "gem install tic_tac_toe"